# Expose jwplayer as a global to import anywhere in app using webpack (Ract+Redux)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I have added jwplayer.js in vendor folder ,and i am trying to import it into my player component to use jwlayer methods. but after importing jwplayer i am getting empty object , may be it is because  , jwplayer is not binded to windows object.

Please have a look at

```
1 ] webpack.config.js

var commonConfig = {
    externals: [{"window": "window"}]
    module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: require.resolve(APP+"/assets/javascript/vendor/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"), loader: 'expose?jwplayer' }
    ],
},
resolve: {
    root: path.join(APP, 'assets'),
    alias: {
        jwplayer: 'javascript/vendor/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'
    }
```

2 ]  jwplayer.js

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import { connect } from 'react-redux'
   import Player from 'jwplayer'

   class Jwplayer extends Component {
      render() {
        console.log(Player)
        return (
           <div className="bigVideo">
           </div>
       )
     }
 }
 export default JwPlayer
```

I am getting empty Player object ?

Please tell me how to bind jwplayer to windows (May be this is the reason)

Comment: what does APP contains? are you using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-webpack-alias) for aliases. SInce you are using expose loader it should be accessible directly you do not need to import it.

Comment: According to [expose loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) it should be expose-loader?player

Comment: I was actually dealing with a similar problem wherein I trying to use the jwplayer.js file you get when you download the production package (7.10.1) as a module with Webpack2. Solution for me was install expose loader and then in my main.js  do: ```require("expose-loader?LibrayName!./jwplayer.js");```